# Search file in perforce by folder pattern

Tags: java, perforce, p4java

I have some Java classes in perforce in different folders for a project. (There are more than one project)

It is possible to search for a file in perforce and get full path of it by just specifying file name and project folder? I mean something like this

Example of folders:

```
//depot/projects/<concrete_proj>/src/java/main/server/services/SomeClass.java
//depot/projects/<concrete_proj>/src/java/main/entities/OtherClass.java
//depot/projects/<concrete_proj>/src/java/main/common/controllers/Controller.java
```

where I believe there is a class that I need:

1.`//depot/projects/<concrete_project>/...@SomeClass.java`

and also situations like this (adding a folder pattern)

2.`//depot/projects/<concrete_project>/...@server@SomeClass.java`

First and second steps above are my assumptions. I tried to find something in documentation, but found nothing about this.

Comment: Are you using visual P4 client ? if yes then did you refer [Searching and Filtering](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/p4v_filters.html)

Comment: Are you looking for `p4 files //depot/projects/.../SomeClass.java`?

Comment: @Mahendra, no I am using command line and P4Java client.
@BryanPendleton, I get as a response `protected namespace` with your command

Comment: @BryanPendleton, thanks for this, I misspelled the path (that's why there was an error), now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet shows how to use `files` command with P4Java:

```
IServer server = ServerFactory.getServer("p4java://repo:1666");
server.setUserName("user");
server.connect();

Map<String, Object>[] result = server.execMapCmd(CmdSpec.FILES.name(), new String[] { "//depot/projects/concrete_project/.../SomeClass.java" }, null);

for (Map<String, Object> entry : result) {
    System.out.println(map.get("depotFile"));
}
```

Valid examples of search strings that cover your use-cases:

```
"//depot/projects/concrete_project/.../Some*.java"
"//depot/projects/concrete_project/.../S*Class.java"
"//depot/projects/concrete_project/.../server/.../SomeClass.java"
"//depot/projects/concrete_project/.../serv*/.../Some*.java"
```

Comment: Thanks mate, maybe for someone it would be helpful, unfortunately I faced this 2 years ago.